# What is the name of this transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have:
* Set of $10$ integers: $\operatorname{Set}={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$
* $\operatorname{2D}$ vectors with integers from the set; for example: $x=(2, 6)$ 

*A integer can't appear twice within a vector.*

I'd like to transform the vectors into a new space; for example: $x=(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)$.

We could see the new form as $10$ flags:

- Is there a $1$ in the initial vector? If yes $1$st element of the new vector is $1$, otherwise $0$.
- Is there a $2$ in the initial vector? If yes 2nd element of the new vector is $1$, otherwise $0$.
- ...

For information $(2, 6)$  and $(6, 2)$  have the same coordinate in the new space.

**Question:** What is the name of this transformation ?

Comment: If no integer can appear twice within a vector, then the vectors are acutally subsets of the "Set". Then I would call the representatation with flags, i.e. $x=(0,1,0,\ldots)$ the "indicator function" of the subset $x = (2,6)$. Denote the indicator function of $x$ by $\chi_x.$ Then $\chi_x$ is a map from "Set" to $\{0,1\}$ which is defined as $\chi_x(m) = 1$ iff $m$ appears in $x$.

Comment: @jflipp: I thought so too, but actually there is a subtlety: the vectors might still be ordered. That makes the transform not 1-to-1, but possibly more useful in OP's context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this transformation has a name, but one of these may help anyway:

- What you describe is a transform from a size-$2$ subset $S$ into what is called it's *characteristic function*, which is usually denoted by $\chi_S$ or $1_S$.
- Your transformation $X$ is formally (symbolically) described as
  $$X: \{(a,b):a,b\in\text{Set}, a\neq b\} \to \{0,1\}^\text{Set}$$
  $$X: \{a,b\} \mapsto \chi_{\{a,b\}}$$